# Sync hotmail calendar with outlook (Without Outlook Connector!)

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, sync, hotmail, windows-live

I have a slightly weird request, but will explain why I need this below.

I want to sync my Hotmail Calendar and Contacts with an Outlook account, without using Outlook Connector and without syncing e-mail.

I need this because I recently created a live account for an e-mail adres I was already using in Outlook. I am using this Live account in Windows Phone for my Contacts and Calendar and it would be very convenient if this info would be synced with Outlook as well. I don't want to directly connect this live account to Outlook because I do not want to sent e-mail through it.

Thanks!

(Ps. Using Outlook 2010)